Does such a manifold exist??
I would REALLY like to find a compact orientable 4-manifold $W$ such that
(i) $\partial W = \mathbb{R}P^3$,
(ii) $H_1(W) = 0$, and
(iii) $H_2(W) = 0$.
This paper seems to be promising, but I'm having trouble understanding it. The second part of Tim Peretz's answer to this question also seems promising, but I don't understand how the diagonal $S^2$ in $S^2 \times S^2$ determines a 4-manifold.
Any and all comments are greatly appreciated!

Just to make sure, you're not assuming that $W$ is compact? I'm asking because the question is easily resolved in the negative for compact manifolds.

Yes, $W$ is compact. I will make an edit.

No such manifold $W$ exists.
To see this, note to start that $H_1(W) = H_2(W) = 0$ implies that $H^1(W) = H^2(W) = 0$ as well, by the universal coefficient theorem. Since you want $W$ to be orientable, we have isomorphisms
$$\newcommand{\RP}{\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}}
    H_k(W) \cong H^{4 - k}(W, \partial W)
$$
for all $k$ by Poincaré-Lefschetz duality. We then have an excerpt of the long exact sequence of the pair $(W, \partial W)$ that reads as follows:
$$
    \cdots \to \underbrace{H^2(W, \partial W)}_{\cong H_2(W) = 0} \to H^2(W) \to H^2(\RP^3) \to \underbrace{H^3(W, \partial W)}_{\cong H_1(W) = 0} \to \cdots
$$
so $0 = H^2(W) \cong H^2(\RP^3) \cong \mathbb{Z} / 2$, which is absurd.

N.b. that the orientability assumption on $W$ is actually not necessary: The same argument works with $\mathbb{F}_2$- instead of $\mathbb{Z}$-coefficients.
